# GLSL Shader Compiles On An Older Computer But Not Another

Tags: opengl, glsl, version, shader

The 'texture' function gives an error when compiling this shader on one computer but not on another. The OpenGL version that the shader compiles on is 3.1. Another computer running OpenGL 4.1 will not compile it though with these errors.

```
0(21) : error C1105: cannot call a non-function
0(58) : error C1105: cannot call a non-function
```

We looked online but could not find the answer. The documentation says that 'texture2D' and 'shadow2D' would work as replacements, but 'shadow2D' gives an error saying it was removed after glsl version 140, even though the OpenGL context is 3.1 in the compiling program. My understanding was that graphics cards were backwards compatible to previous glsl versions.

Here's the problem shader:

```
#version 140

in vec3 position;
in vec2 texCoord;
in vec3 normal;

out vec3 normalView_vs;
out vec3 normalShadow_vs;
out vec3 eyeView_vs;
out vec3 lightDirView_vs;
out vec2 texCoord_vs;
out vec4 shadowCoord_vs;

uniform mat4 worldMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 depthModelProjectionMatrix;
uniform vec3 sunDirection;

const mat4 biasMatrix = mat4(0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                             0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                             0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
                             0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

void main(void)
{
    eyeView_vs = -(viewMatrix * worldMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f)).xyz;

    lightDirView_vs = (viewMatrix*vec4(sunDirection, 0.0f)).xyz;

    normalShadow_vs = (depthModelProjectionMatrix * vec4(normal, 0.0f)).xyz;
    normalView_vs = (viewMatrix * worldMatrix * vec4(normal, 0.0f)).xyz;
    // Note: Only correct if worldMatrix does not scale the model ! Use its inverse transpose if not.

    gl_Position = modelProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);
    texCoord_vs = texCoord;
    shadowCoord_vs = biasMatrix * depthModelProjectionMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: Multiline `const mat4` initialization seems to be the problem, check for hidden chars, try it on a single line, check line break rules, etc...(only if `0(21)` points to the error, but I'm not sure)

Comment: `shadow2D` and `texture2D` aren't even part of GLSL 1.40. They were removed in GLSL 1.30. Just use `texture(...)` instead, beginning with GLSL 1.30, that function is overloaded to do the same things you used to have to use different functions for (e.g. 3D texture lookup, shadow comparison, etc.).

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any samplers or texture calls here. Did you post the vertex shader instead of the fragment shader?